# Azure Api Management Gateway Consumption Tier - How to Find IP Address

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an Azure Web App to that I'd like to secure by allowing only requests from the Azure Api Management Gateway - Consumption Tier. In order to do this I think I need to know Gateway's IP Address.

Does anyone know how to find this through the new Azure Portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consumption SKU uses dynamic hosting model, so it's not guaranteed to have stable IP address. You need to look into other security measures to ensure that your backend is callable only by APIM, like using client certificate authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the ip address on the overview page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I should have mentioned in the question that I'm using the "Consumption" tier. Maybe this is the reason the VIP address is not displayed on the overview page