# Azure API management URL is not connected to API

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I am new to API Management. I have created a Management resource which I have connected a Functions App to, furthermore I have made sure that a subscription is required to access the API/Functions App. In the Functions App Networking-settings, I have disabled "public network access" since I only want to give access through the API Management.

Does anyone know how I can create an API Management resource with an API (as a functions app) connected to the APIM which requires a subscription key and has disabled public network access?

Thank you

First of all, when I try to test the API in the Azure Portal I can not see that the request passes a subscription key, which seems weird to me. And when i send the request, I get this error back

[image: Error API Management]

Answer (score 0):

To access the function app in Azure APIM by disabling **public network access**, you need to add a new rule in function app and allow the public IP of APIM.

- Fetch the public IP from APIM **Overview** menu.

[image]

- Then add a new rule in function app as shown below.

[image]
[image]

- By doing so, you can only grant access to APIM and can invoke the function.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, however I believe that this is only available for the Developer tier, I am using the Consumption tier, since i want to access the API from outside of Azure portal, for example with Postman

Comment: If you have disabled public network access then you need to allow the IPs where you are accessing the function or else you will get forbidden response

Comment: @dev-d4 In this way, you can also invoke the APIM Url from postman

Comment: Lets say that I allow the IP address that I'm currently using, then I will be able to access the Functions App without the subscription key (which i dont want to be possible). From what I have learned, it should be possible to disable public network access for the functions app, but access it through the API Management service with a subscription key

Comment: Which subscription key you are talking here function's or APIM's?

Comment: @dev-d4 In my setup, I have created an anonymous function and then disabled public network access, then added the APIM's IP in allowed list. Post this I am able to invoke the function like [this](https://i.imgur.com/TKsFw4c.png)

Comment: APIM's subscription key

Comment: If you want to pass the key then you can enable it or else disable it in portal

Comment: Yes, I think this works if the APIM is set up in the developer tier, however I am using the Consumption Tier which does not allow the APIM to have an IP, which is why i can not add it to the allowed list

Comment: @dev-d4 You can get the IP's for consumption tier too. Invoke any of your endpoint in portal and check the value of `X-Forwarded-For` in trace like [this](https://i.imgur.com/7eykDvX.png) and add these IP's in rule. You will get the output

Comment: I have managed to get the X-Forwarded-For value, however how do i add this to the allowed IPs for the Functions App?

Comment: Go to Networking and check my answer

Comment: Okay thank you. However, according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936691/23194630, using the IP adress for an APIM with a consumption tier is not a stable way to do it, I'm now looking at alternative ways to connect the API to the APIM